# Can we access any files in phone directory after an apk file has been installed?

Tags: android

I'm developing an Android App, a Book. It is a long with many contents paragraph. I'm thinking about dividing that paragraph into small paragraphs and store them in database using `SQLite` Database by creating a table with these attributes: `ID`,`Title`,`Path`,... I store those small paragraph in text files and copy them into phone directory. I want to ask that can we access those files by their path in phone directory? if yes then how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Find the directory for the SD Card using the API
//*Don't* hardcode "/sdcard"
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

//Get the text file
File file = new File(sdcard,"file.txt");

//Read text from file
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String line;

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        text.append(line);
        text.append('\n');
    }
}
catch (IOException e) {
    //You'll need to add proper error handling here
}

//Find the view by its id
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_view);

//Set the text
tv.setText(text);
```

I hope its useful to you..

Comment: this really helpful for me